# What is pale pilsen?

Tags: style

We have this local beer in the Philippines called San Miguel Pale Pilsen. Looking at this [style guide](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/catdex.php) I don't see any mention of the word Pilsen, though there is the word Pilsner. Are they in any way related?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are related. The pilsner beer style got its name from the city of [Pilsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plze%C5%88), in what is now the Czech Republic, where the beer was first brewed in 1842.

Reference: [Pilsner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilsner)

Comment: I knew it! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Other common variants are _pilsener_ or just _pils_.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your question asked about a "pale pilsen" the answer would be that this is in a way a pleonasm since Pilsner/Pils/Pilsen is a lager beer brewed with pale malt and therefore pale by definition. The only not so super pale Pilsner I've seen so far is the Imperial Pilsner "Draft Bear" by Mikkeller which still is quite pale and also a very lose interpretation of the style.